# Boolean variable based on object property

Tags: javascript

I'm totally stuck with something that might be very basic:

I'm using a constructor to create several game items:

```
function itemCreator(itemName, itemType, itemPosition) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.itemType = itemType;
            this.itemPosition =itemPosition;
}

 new itemCreator('shootUp001', 'item_up', 108 );

 new itemCreator('shootLeft001', 'item_left', 608);

 new itemCreator('shootLeft002', 'item_left', 40);
```

Later I'm assigning images for the items like this:

```
function assignImages(item){
    itemObject =item;
    itemType = itemObject.itemType;
    var itemDiv = document.getElementById(itemType); //get the div that has the name of this item
    itemDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' +itemType +'.png"/><span class="x">x</span><span id="' +itemType +'SpanCount"></span>' //put the picture of this item in there and also a span for the counting
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck:

How can I create a boolean variable that I set to "true" when I have inserted the image of a certain itemType for the first time? I'm need this to avoid inserting the same type of image twice.

I know I could do a simple dom lookup, but I'm trying to learn javascript and would like to understand how I could to avoid that in this situation.

So what would be a smart way of creating a variable based on the itemType and modifying that variable when assignImage is passed an object with a matching itemType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed your class itemType to Item just to follow standard Javascript convention where we name our classes with a capital letter to start the name. Below is how I would keep track of itemtypes already created using a simple dictionary:

```
var images = {};//keeping track of images by item types so far

function assignImages(item){
    var type = item.itemType
    if(!images.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
        var itemDiv = document.getElementById(type); //get the div that has the name of this item
        itemDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' +type +'.png"/><span class="x">x</span><span id="' +type +'SpanCount"></span>' //put the picture of this item in there and also a span for the counting
        images[type] = itemDiv;
    } else {
        console.warn("A image of item type %s already exists", type);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you actually modifying `items`?

Comment: @Pavlo On line 5 of the Item class - I'm assigning the item instance to the itemType in items.

Comment: Here's the problem: if I read your code correctly, you are creating the properties only if an item with the same itemType doesn't exist. But I need all the items, regardless if they have the same itemType. I simply need to assign the image only once per itemType.

Comment: I think it might.. I'm still trying to understand this part: 
    
    images[type] = itemDiv;

Are you putting the image dom-element to the images variable? Do we really need to store so much data?

Comment: You're storing a reference to a DOM element - the `images` ductionary just references a bunch of pointers and doesnt actually hold that much data. You can store a boolean instead but holding the DOM element may be useful for you later if you want to operate on the element of a certain item type

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining! I'm accepting this as the answer!

Comment: Note: it adds one more thing you must check if you plan to dispose of the DOM element because then it can become a waste of memory if it's referencing a dead element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning images to the items you should do it to the type.
Get all the unique item types and then assign the image to those.

```
function itemCreator(itemName, itemType, itemPosition) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.itemType = itemType;
            this.itemPosition =itemPosition;
}

function assignImages(itemType){
    var itemDiv = document.getElementById(itemType);
    itemDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="' +itemType +'.png"/><span class="x">x</span><span id="' +itemType +'SpanCount"></span>'
}

var list = [
    new itemCreator('shootUp001', 'item_up', 108),
    new itemCreator('shootLeft001', 'item_left', 608),
    new itemCreator('shootLeft002', 'item_left', 40)
];

var unique_types = list.map(function(i) {
        return i.itemType;
    }).reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);

unique_types.forEach(function(itemType){
    assignImages(itemType);
});
```

Comment: Ouch, I'm sure this is a decent solution but the unique_types function is waay over my current understanding :/